# Restricting solution $x$ to $Ax = b$ to natural numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is $(n-1) \times n$ matrix that consists only of natural numbers (that is 0 and positive integers.) $b$ is $(n-1) \times 1$ matrix (vector) that only consists of natural numbers.

For the solution $x$ of $Ax =b$, the number of solutions will be infinite (if there's solution). But would there be a way to easily restrict the solution $x$ to consist only of natural numbers? Would there be a way like extending $A$ and $b$ to be $n \times n$ matrix that incorporates natural number requirement for $xE$?

Comment: Note that there could be no solutions to $Ax=b$; for example if every row of $A$ is the same, but $b$ has some non-equal entries.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0\neq v\in ker(A)$, which is nonzero by dimension counting. Then $A(x+v)=b$. Let $A'x'=b'$, then $A'(x'+v)=A'x'+A'v=b'$. But clearly $x+v$ cannot always be an integer.